# xhprof_enable is undefined, even after loading module in php.ini

Tags: xhprof

I've installed xhprof but Apache is not loading the extension.

The extension is loaded in the php.ini, but I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function xhprof_enable() in /home/bd/public_html/application/hooks/xhprof.php on line 15
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because the xhprof is no accurately loaded.If use the commod 'php -m', maybe you will find there is no xhprof.

You can check if you have added the flowing to the 'php.ini'.

```
[xhprof]
extension=xhprof.so
xhprof.output_dir=/tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.

I am using PHP5.6 so i could easily install XhProf using the following:

```
apt-get install php5.6-xhprof
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've forgotten to restart php-fpm (or Apache, or other servers related with php, depends on which server you use).

After restart php-fpm (or Apache), you may meet the following (via phpinfo()):

[image: xhprof within phpinfo()]

And then, `xhprof_enable()` works.

Answer (score -1):

You need reload the `php-fpm` service.